# Altering the user-agent string with the HTMLControl

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm writing an app (VS2005, C++, targeting WM5) which is hosting the HTML Control.  Can I modify the user-agent this control uses when making a request to a server?

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.addheader.aspx

Use AddHeader to modify the useragent.

Since you are in a control, use this to get to your current HttpResponse object.
this.Page.Response.AddHeader

Comment: He doesn't have an HttpResponse object. The question wants to know how to change the agent string being sent from an HTMLControl.

Comment: Sure he does.  Just reference the current page's HttpResponse object.

Comment: I'm not using .Net CF.  Is the HttpResponse object available by accessing a particular COM Interface?